# What kind of action is used to activate the hex Prehensile Hair?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, witch

This hex specifically says instantly (which is quite ambiguous).

> Effect: The witch can instantly cause her hair (or even her eyebrows)
>   to grow...

But, hexes are typically activated with a standard action as default:

> Unless otherwise noted, using a hex is a standard action that does not
>   provoke an attack of opportunity.

Maybe it can be activated as a free action?

Comment: Make a fey trickster mesmerist and get the Rusalka's Tresses at lv 20.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## A creature must take a standard action to activate the [witch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/) [hex](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Witch/#TOC-Hex) [prehensile hair](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/hex-prehensile-hair-su/)

Like most witch hexes without a stated activated time, the activation time of the witch hex [prehensile hair](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/hex-prehensile-hair-su/) is a standard action. While the unfortunate use of the word *instantly* in the hex's description has led to debate on this topic on the Paizo messageboards (e.g. this thread from [2011](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2n1nv?The-flight-and-prehensile-hair-hexes-and)), creative director James Jacobs clarifies in [this 2012 exchange](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=474?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#23657) that activating the hex is, in fact, a standard action:

> **Question:** What kind of action is activating a witch Prehensile Hair?
>   it is a hex, so apparently it is a standard action, but the power say they grow instantly.…
>
> ***Answer:*** Using the ability is a standard action, but the strands themselves lengthen as appropriate to do the task they need to do without you needing to spend an action to do so.

While not a rules guy, Jacobs's clarification makes it clear that the hex prehensile hair jibes with the rest of the game rather than the description's use of the word *instantly* possessing secret mechanical value.

Answer (score 7):

### A standard action

Despite the flavor text (*instantly grows*), there is no mention that this *instant* takes a swift or even a free action, and as such, remains a *Standard Action*, the default action to activate hexes.

Note that your hair grows once the hex is *activated*, and activating it takes a standard. Once its activated, the hair grows instantly.